# Why is this a SVN conflict for Subversive?

Tags: java, svn, subversive, conflict

I'm writing a desktop app that must work on both Linux and Windows because on Windows I need to use JNI to implement a functionality. But that's not the problem.
I have a Windows and a Linux installation of the Eclipse IDE and I use Subversive to commit to my repository.
After a Windows commit I started working on Linux to implement the linux implementation but I find myself with a conflict:

*.classpath [Working]*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/sqlitejdbc-v056.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

*.classpath[Repository]*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/sqlitejdbc-v056.jar">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.CLASSPATH_ATTR_LIBRARY_PATH_ENTRY" value="QuickBackup/bin"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

As you can see the conflict is in the *`<attribute>...</attribute>`* part which is used to tell the jvm where is my dll module to use with jni. Why? Coundn't Subversive just update the working version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 problems with different nature. First, svn conflict arises if you modify file from working copy with rev 156, but in the meantime this file from someone else's working copy was committed to rev 157. When you update your file, two scenarios can occur:

- merged (G): means that you and your colleague were working on the file but on different places, so the 'diff' utility thinks it is OK to merge it.
- conflict (C): the 'diff' utility determined that both yours and your colleague's changes were incompatible, so you'll need to resolve the differences on (only) yours working copy

The second problem is ini (or conf) files that are not deployment-agnostic. What I mean is, this file should be different on each machine where the code is deployed. In this case (and I think this is your case) you'll need to put svn:ignore property on it, and remember to create this file and put its specifics on every deployment.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html#svn-ch-7-sect-2.3.3

Comment: Well, I'm working alone so I assumed that, since the user who was committing and then updating was the same guy, this kind of conflict should not be there.

Comment: Nope, the svn looks at different working copies' commits, that's how it determined the diff's, by checking your local code and the rev you're trying to update to. I also have 3-4 different working copy (home, laptop, work, stage-server) and svn is great help to synchronize.

Comment: Ok, tnx! Do you realize different working copies just choosing files to svn:ignore or do you need to create a "profile"?

Comment: Well, what I do is to move all the stuff from the code that is deployment-dependent to a conf file (this should contain db-connection strings, lib-paths, resources-path, log-paths etc), and then set the svn:ignore property to the conf file. When you commit its parent folder, the property will be set in the repository, and it will apply to all of the working copies. So to answer your question, tag this file of yours with svn:ignore, commit its folder, and the svn will do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes version control systems just can't figure out what to do with changes. It could me for any number of reasons. But determining how to merge changes in a repository like this is very much not a trivial thing to do.